# CSS - Force flexbox to utilize vertical height

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a decent navigation bar filled with a logo image however the text refuses to utilize any vertical height and I need the text-box to utilize 100% of it's vertical height [image]
As you can see in the image, the textbox is only clickable within that border and it isn't using any vertical height which I want it to use

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");

.navigation-bar {
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #e31f1f;
}

.navigation-item {
    height: 100%
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #4848b9;
    flex: 1 1 35em;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.navigation-item a {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
}

.navigation-item a:hover {
}

.current-item {
}

.logo {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>heading</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
      <div><a class="current-item navigation-item" href="home.html">Home</a></div>
      <div><a class="navigation-item" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></div>
      <div><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" height=128 alt="logo" class="logo navigation-item" /></div>
      <div><a class="navigation-item" href="about-us.html">About Us</a></div>
      <div><a class="navigation-item" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you want to place your logo?

Comment: To what are you setting the height? I can't see any height setting, what am I missing?

Comment: @AHaworth I haven't added a height specification, but I have tried it to not much success

Comment: When you do add a height what are you adding it to?

Comment: In the middle  .

Comment: @AHaworth I'm trying to change the text borders to utilize vertical height so that they can be tapped from the bottom of the navigation bar as well

Comment: Could you please add an example of this to your code because I can't make sense of the description you have just given. Thanks.

Comment: To get the items using the overall height switch to using grid rather than flex for the main bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid` for your container to make the row occupy exactly `1fr`. After that just add `flexbox` to your `div`'s that are directly below your parent container to enable `flex-grow` on your `navigation-item` or `<a>` tags. After that it's just a matter of centering the text vertically and horizontally inside the `navigation-item`. See the snippet below, if it's what's you're looking for.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation-bar {
  padding: 3px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  background-color: #e31f1f;
}

.navigation-item {
  border: 1px solid #4848b9;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.navigation-bar > div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-item a:hover {}

.current-item {}

.logo {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>heading</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation-bar">
    <div><a class="current-item navigation-item" href="home.html">Home</a></div>
    <div><a class="navigation-item" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" height=128 alt="logo" class="logo navigation-item" /></div>
    <div><a class="navigation-item" href="about-us.html">About Us</a></div>
    <div><a class="navigation-item" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```